# ERROR Adaptive Server Requires encryption of the login password on the network - SQL Server Migration Assistant for Sybase

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sybase, password-encryption, dbmigrate

I'm trying to migrate Sybase Database to an SQL Server by assistant tool from Microsoft. When I try to connect to Sybase with ODBC Driver Provider in SQL Server Migration the error bellow appears.

> ERROR [ZZZZZ][SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.
> ERROR [ZZZZZ][SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Login failed.

Analyzing my connection configured in ODBC Data Source Administrator I noticed that the Encrpyt Password flag is set and the Test Connection works fine (Login Succeeded).

I've been searching for a encrypt password connection string but I got other error

> [IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

> ERROR [ZZZZZ][SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network

![ERROR [ZZZZZ][SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqYGN.png)

[image: ODBC Test Connection]

[image: Connection String Error]

Comment: From your question it seems that you have done initial trouble shooting. I am slightly confused by what is your actual problem. RE: "Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network." - have you looked at [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sybase/connecting-to-sybase-ase-sybasetosql?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: Another alternative re-configure Sybase to no longer require encrypted passwords.